# What is the probability of at least one success in 6 attempts when 9 out of 1000 integers are successful?

Tags: probability

In a raffle there are 6 prizes. Tickets are numbered 1 to 1000 (only integers). 6 tickets are drawn, without replacement. I hold 9 tickets (eg. numbers 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900). What is the probability I get at least one of my tickets drawn?

What is the general formula for a question like this? (With different numbers of tickets drawn, tickets owned and total tickets available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the number of tickets drawn that are yours. Then

$$\begin{align*}
P(X\geq1)
&=1-P(X=0)\\\\
&=1-\left(\frac{991}{1000}\cdot\frac{990}{999}\cdot\frac{989}{998}\cdot\frac{988}{997}\cdot\frac{987}{996}\cdot\frac{986}{995}\right)\\\\
&\approx0.0529
\end{align*}$$

since the first has to be one of the $991$ that are not yours. Then take that ticket away and the next has to be one of the $990$ that are not yours, of the $999$ tickets remaining, and so forth.

I wrote it as

$$1-\left(\frac{991}{1000}\cdot\frac{990}{999}\cdot\frac{989}{998}\cdot\frac{988}{997}\cdot\frac{987}{996}\cdot\frac{986}{995}\right)$$

for sake of demonstration but this is equivalent to

$$1-\frac{{991 \choose 6}}{{1000 \choose 6}}\approx0.0529$$

since we are taking the compliment of choosing $6$ cards of the $991$ that aren't yours of the $1000$ total.

In general, letting $n$ be the number of tickets in total, $k$ being the number of tickets that you hold, $j$ being the number of tickets drawn, and $X$ being the number of tickets drawn that are yours, we have

$$P(X\geq1)=1-\frac{{n-k \choose j}}{{n \choose j}}$$

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve it like this:

Since there are 1000 tickets and 6 prizes, there are ${1000 \choose 6}$ possible ways. The probability that you win nothing is given by ${991 \choose 6}$. The probability that you will not win is thus given by ${991 \choose 6} \over {1000 \choose 6}$ so the probability that you win is just the compliment of that: $$1 - {{991 \choose 6} \over {1000 \choose 6}} \approx 0.052928$$ If this doesn't make sense, I'd recommend you touch up on combinations. Hope this helps!